# How to remove the function hooked to action within a class

Tags: plugins, filters, actions

I want to remove the function `listify_single_job_listing_meta` which is hooked in action inside the following class

```
class Listify_WP_Job_Manager_Template extends listify_Integration {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->includes = array();
        $this->integration = 'wp-job-manager';

        $this->is_home = false;

        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function setup_actions() {      


        add_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_meta', array( $this, 'single_job_listing_meta' ) );
    }



public function single_job_listing_meta() {
        do_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_start' );

        do_action( 'single_job_listing_meta_end' );    

    }

    }
```

I am using the following code in functions.php

```
global $myclass;
$myclass='Listify_WP_Job_Manager_Template';
remove_action( 'listify_single_job_listing_meta', array( $myclass, 'single_job_listing_meta' ) );
```

But this is not giving me the desired result .
Please help

Comment: @toscho thanks , but there is nothing related to removing the function

Comment: If `single_job_listing_meta()` isn't a static method, you **have** to access the same instance.

Comment: @toscho i think its static method because it has been defined as public. I have edited my code  public single_job_listing_meta()

Comment: Nah, a static method would be declared as `static`.